# Tensor product of graded algebras 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, tensor-products, graded-rings

Let $A,B$ be two graded algebras. We know that $$f:A \otimes B \to B \otimes A$$ defined by $f(a\otimes b)= (-1)^{\deg a.\deg b}(b \otimes a)$ is isomorphism.

My question is

(i) Why $f(a\otimes b)= (-1)^{\deg a.\deg b}(b \otimes a)$ ? instead $f(a\otimes b)= b \otimes a$ ?

(ii) If $A,B,C$ are three graded algebras then so is $A \otimes B  \otimes C.$ determined graded algebra structure  over $A \otimes B  \otimes C.$?

Answer (score 3):

I assume that $A,B$ are graded commutative. Then the graded product on $B \otimes A$ is defined on homogeneous tensors by

$$ (b \otimes a) \cdot (b' \otimes a') = (-1)^{\deg b' \deg a} (b \cdot b') \otimes (a \cdot a') $$

where the sign is there so that the product will be commutative in the graded sense and similarly for $A \otimes B$. Then the sign factor in the definition of $f$ is there in order to make $f$ a homomorphism:

$$ f((a \otimes b) \cdot (a' \otimes b')) = f((-1)^{\deg b \deg a'} (a \cdot a') \otimes (b \cdot b')) = (-1)^{\deg b \deg a'}(-1)^{\deg(a \cdot a') \deg(b \cdot b')} (b \cdot b') \otimes (a \cdot a') = (-1)^{\deg b \deg a' + \deg a \deg b + \deg a \deg b' + \deg a' \deg b + \deg b \deg b'} (b \cdot b') \otimes (a \cdot a') \\
= (-1)^{\deg a \deg b'} (-1)^{\deg a \deg b} (b \otimes a) \cdot (-1)^{\deg a' \deg b'} (b' \otimes a') = f( a \otimes b) \cdot f(a' \otimes b').$$

Comment: @ levap. Thanks! Why $\deg(a.a').\deg(b.b') = \deg a.\deg b + \deg a.\deg b' + \deg a'.\deg b + \deg b.\deg b'$ ?

Comment: Since $A$ is graded, we have $\deg(a \cdot a') = \deg a + \deg a'$ and similarly for $B$.

Comment: @ levap. If  $A, B, C$ are three graded commutative algebras then $A \otimes B \otimes C$ to be graded commutative also. My question is $(x \otimes y \otimes k)(z \otimes t \otimes \ell) = ?$

Comment: @longhoang: If you know how to make a tensor product of two graded commutative algebras, you also know how to make a tensor product of three graded commutative algebras. Write $A \otimes B \otimes C \approx (A \otimes B) \otimes C$.

Comment: @ levap. I find an answer for my question at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1893589/tensor-products-of-three-graded-algebras but I don't understand why $abca'b'c' = (-1)^{\deg a'.\deg c}aba'cb'c'.$ Can you explain to me?